# How to create an array and add data to it in vue

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to create a simple array that would copy already existing data from array of objects in an API.

All of this I do in the  part of the code.
I declare my array in:

```
data() {
   return {
      Data: null, //this is getting data from API correctly I am interested in Data.hourly[i].dt values(Data.hourly[0].dt = some value (works))
      timetable: [] }}
```

later I made a method in methods(which I call I checked it) to methods:

```
insertTimeTable(){
  for (i in Data.hourly) 
  {
    this.timetable.push({
      date: this.Data.hourly[i].dt})
  }
}
```

How to make it work and why it does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are forgetting to add `this` to Data.hourly in for loop

```
insertTimeTable(){
  for (let i in this.Data.hourly) 
  {
    this.timetable.push({
      date: this.Data.hourly[i].dt})
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, but it still won't work even with this fix.

Comment: one issue could be that you are getting the value from API... maybe function insertTimeTable()  gets called before the value is passed to Data object

Comment: I have updated my code, you need to declare variable you are using inside for loop..